# onSubmit form call an exernal javascript file from another folder

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to call an external javascript file that its on another folder for a specific form. when i keep the javascript code into the file of the form, the javascript executed perfectly . But I created another javascript file for that and I want to call it into my form.

Can you please tell me how exactly to change my code
OPEN TO ANY SUGGESTIONS

form

```
 <form id = "additems" action="../cms/insert.php" onsubmit="return allnumeric(price,stock)" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" />
        <div id="formContents">
          <label for="title">Title of your product:
          <div id="formContents"> </label><input type="text" name="title" style="width: 180px"  /><p>
          </div>
              <div id="formContents">
          <label for="description">Description of your product:
          <div id="formContents"> </label><input type="text" name="description" style="width: 180px" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value=''"    
                onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue" 
                value=" description of the product" maxlength="19" /><p>
          </div>
          <label for="price">Price:      &pound;    </label><input type="INT" name="price" style="width: 40px" /><p>
          <label for="stock">Quantity:</label><input type="text" name="stock" style="width: 40px" />
```

validate.js

```
<script>
{
var x=document.forms["additems"]["title"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("Please fill out the TITLE of your product");
  return false;
  }

var y=document.forms["additems"]["price"].value;
if (y==null || y=="")
  {
  alert("Please fill out the PRICE of your product");
  return false;
  }

var z=document.forms["additems"]["stock"].value;
if (z==null || z=="")
  {
  alert("Please fill out the QUANTITY of your product");
  return false;
  }

}
function allnumeric(price,stock)  
   {  
   validateForm();
      var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;  
      if(!price.value.match(numbers))   
          {  
          alert('PRICE--Please input numeric characters only');  
          return false;  
          }
      else if(!stock.value.match(numbers))
            {  
                alert('STOCk--Please input numeric characters only');  
                return false;  
            }    
   }  
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a call to load the javascript file in your form file?

Within the `<head>` tag you should have something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="somefile.js"></script>
```

You'll need to add a relative path in front of somefile.js if they're not in the same directory.

Comment: and what about the form? the onsubmit= ??? should it be the name of the js file?or the path?

Comment: <form id = "additems" action="../cms/insert.php" onsubmit="return allnumeric(price,stock)" /> -- what i need to add here?this is the function of the js file i want to call. shall i call the file or the function?

Comment: You would put the function name, yes, just as you did when the script was in the page. The script tag is essentially pulling the script into the page for you.